# The use of "in the process"

Tags: grammar, meaning

> In all these examples we are confronted with the distinction between
> an objective process, in which something undergoes change, and the
> concepts in terms of which we try to sum up the characteristics of the
> things involved **in the process**. Such concepts never do and never can
> always and in all respects correspond to their objects, precisely
> because the objects are undergoing change.

[From Materialism and the Dialectical Method (Maurice Cornforth)]

I am confused about the use of "in the process" in the context above. It refers to "objective process", isn't it?

Comment: "It refers to 'objective process' _doesn't_ it?" Yes, it does.

Comment: Yes, there's an idiom "[in the process](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-the-process)" meaning "as a result of doing something else at the same time" but this is just a literal use, not the idiom.